# How to prevent auto-launching of our iOS app from links in FB iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook

We have an iOS app that publishes certain activity to Facebook that contains links to pages on our domain. Our intention is for friends to click on those links and view them as webpages.

However, when you click on links in these published stories in the FB iOS app, it's auto launching our app instead of going to an embedded Web View or kicking out to safari.

Note: We still want to have single sign on (SSO), so just want to change the behavior of clicking links in published stories.

To clarify, this is what I'm talking about:

1. My app is able to publishes http://foo.com/123 into the FB newsfeed for a particular user that opts in.
2. That person's friends see the link, but when they click it, it just goes to http://foo.com/123 in the browser instead of launching my FOO app. This is because my app doesn't yet handle incoming context from FB iOS app.
3. I still want FB SSO to work from my FOO app. That is, when clicking on FB sign in in my FOO app, it jumps out to the FB iOS app (if installed) and does a single sign on and redirects back to my app.  IOW, I don't want to break this authentication scenario that currently works.

What setting in the FB developers App Settings controls this? It's not clear from the documentation.  I see sections for `Native iOS app` and `Website` which I currently have set but it's unclear which sub-setting affects the behavior in question. Also, it's not clear even if I was to find the setting, can I affect it without affecting SSO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting you want in the Facebook App dialog is under the iOS Native section (see the screenshot below) - set both the highlighted sections to Disabled.

[image: App Settings dialog]

This won't affect Facebook login/SSO in the app, so you'll still be able to do the OAuth dances.

Comment: Your answer is correct.  I figured this out awhile back after I posted this but never updated my question with an answer.